# How to link JSON file so that it can be parsed and used to create an arraylist

Tags: javascript, html, json, arraylist

I would like my program to import an JSON file, using the data to create an array-list then access the array-list so that I can display it on the web page.

I've tried using `JSON.parse()` but it only works when I do something like `JSON.parse('[{"shape":"polygon"},{"shape":"square"}]);` It doesn't work for parsing a JSON file that is not declared inside. My JSON file is saved to my desktop. I'm new to JavaScript and importing files so anything would be helpful!

I've tried using:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "PATIENT51.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I keep getting errors with: `JSON.parse(this.responseText);`

JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:5  problemlist1.html(3,5)

Comment: It may be a cors issue issue if you're running this locally. What errors are you getting in console? Copy and paste them into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just have the log in xmlhttp scope and it'll work.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText))
}
};
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "PATIENT51.txt", true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

EDIT: seen your edit, in addition, make sure that your JSON has the right format:

```
{
"key1" : 1,
"key2" : 2,
"key3" : 3
}
```

Comment: What if my JSON file looked like this
{
“resourceType”:”RiskAssessment”,
“Notes”: [
{“date”: “05/13/2019”, “note”: “my notes”},
{“date”: “02/22/2018”, “note”: “cool”}
]
}
How do I access the 05/13/2019, I’ve tried using 
myObj.note[0].note;
But I get “undefined” as a result

Comment: myObj.Notes[0].note

myobj is an Object which has an Array inside it under the key "Notes" so we get inside it after the first .    , in this array there are 2 objects, the keys of an array are of course it's index, starts with a 0. so we need the first item in the Array, pointing it with it's index, then we have an object again so point the wanted key called "note" and that's it.